# Read(u=UNIT,*) reads just half the file in fortran

Tags: file-io, fortran

so I'm trying to make a Fortran subroutine that reads a matrix (or a tensor I guess) of size 125x125x125 from a file that I create in another subroutine, but for some reason it doesn't work. I have successfully done it using almost the same program but for a different size of matrix (70x200x70) and for some reason when I change the size of the arrays and a couple of other things to fit the new data, the program reads just half the data file and throws an error that says `At line 133 of file Busqueda.f90 (unit = 2, file = 'test2.txt') Fortran runtime error: End of file`. So my working code is:

```
Subroutine DataSorting(datasort,indexsort,datosden,datostemp)
use globals
implicit None
real*8, dimension(70,200,70)              :: datosdentemp
real*8, dimension(70,200,70), intent(out) :: datostemp, datosden
real*8, dimension(980000), intent(out)    :: datasort
integer,dimension(3,980000),intent(out) :: indexsort
integer, dimension(3) :: Result
integer               :: i
rewind(2)
read(2,*) datosden
datosdentemp = datosden
rewind(3)
read(3,*) datostemp
do i = 1, 10
    Result = MAXLOC(datosdentemp)
    datasort(i) = datosden(Result(1),Result(2),Result(3))
    indexsort(1,i) = Result(1)
    indexsort(2,i) = Result(2)
    indexsort(3,i) = Result(3)
    datosdentemp(Result(1),Result(2),Result(3)) = 0
end do
End Subroutine DataSorting
```

And the code that dont work is:

```
Subroutine DataSorting(datasort,indexsort,datosden,datostemp)
use globals
implicit None
real*8, dimension(125,125,125)              :: datosdentemp
real*8, dimension(125,125,125), intent(out) :: datostemp, datosden
real*8, dimension(1953125), intent(out)    :: datasort
integer,dimension(3,1953125),intent(out) :: indexsort
integer, dimension(3) :: Result
integer               :: i
rewind(2)
read(2,*) datosden
datosdentemp = datosden
rewind(3)
read(3,*) datostemp
do i = 1, 10
    Result = MAXLOC(datosdentemp)
    datasort(i) = datosden(Result(1),Result(2),Result(3))
    indexsort(1,i) = Result(1)
    indexsort(2,i) = Result(2)
    indexsort(3,i) = Result(3)
    datosdentemp(Result(1),Result(2),Result(3)) = 0
end do
End Subroutine DataSorting
```

The files from where I'm reading the data just have the data arranged in 125 columns and 15625 rows in the case of the non-working program, and in 70 columns and 14000 rows for the working one, and the files are just that, I mean they are really structured that way in both cases. I was using scratch files for the files 2 and 3, and change them to '.txt' files to see if there was a problem with the input file, but no. Then I build a new file and did the reading with a do-loop, to see if that was the problem, but no, but at least that helped me to realize that the code was reading exactly half of 15625, but i don't know why this is happening, I'm new to fortran, my thesis advisor told me to do this code in Fortran 'cause the amount of data that have to handle will make my Julia code way to slow, so honestly any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Be aware that Fortran 90 is just one very old standard revision, now mostly obsolete, and your `real*8` syntax is not just not Fortran 90 conforming, it is not standard Fortran at all.

Comment: Definitely try to read just part of the data and print it to see if it looks correct. For more, a real [mcve] is probably needed.

Comment: I would read it a line at a time, and check that there is data in your file after the last line that is successfully read - as currently presented my guess is a problem in the file, but without a minimal reproducible example it is difficult to test any ideas

Comment: How does your error message map onto your code? Your code doesn't have a line 133.

Comment: Possibly irrelevant comment: redefine the array arguments to use *assumed-shape* (*eg* replace `dimension(70,200,70)` with `dimension(:,:,:)`).  That way you only have one version of the subroutine to debug.  It also eliminates a source of fragility in the program, fragile things often break when handled roughly.

Comment: @VladimirF So i tried to 
'do i=1,xdim
do j=1,ydim
read(2,*) (dataden(i,j,z),z=1,zdim)
write(4,*) (dataden(i,j,z),z=1,zdim)'
and that's how i realize that it only read until the half line, also i tried to change the order of the write and read and do both of them on the same file, to create the file and then read it immediately, but that didn't work.

Comment: Do not put code into comments. Edit your question to create some reasonably complete minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @veryreverie Thats not the entire program, it's just the subroutine thats giving me problem, the line 133 it's this line `read(2,*) datosden`, I guess i should put the entire program then

Comment: I am aware :) But since the error message doesn't quote any code, and you have only given a snippet rather than a minimal reproducible example, we can only guess which line of your snippet the error message refers to.